# SQL server SELECT clause in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table Status which contains recid, instituitionid, filename, status, etc.

recid is the primary key and would be unique.

I want to have a query where the all row are selected from a table with a particular instituitionid and filename. The issue is that I only have the recid as the input & the 2 parameter values would be the same as values which are the values of the recid I have.

It would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM Status 
WHERE instituitionid = (SELECT instituitionid FROM Status WHERE recid = recid) 
AND filename = (SELECT filename FROM Status WHERE recid = recid)
```

Though am sure many ppl would have asked this, I couldn't find the syntax for this from my searching.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  lot of ways to do this:  here's another:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM   Status s
 WHERE  EXISTS (
     SELECT  1 
     FROM    Status s2
     WHERE   s.institutionid = s2.institutionid
        AND  s.filename = s2.filename
        AND  s2.recid = @recid

 )
```

Since you say you have the `recid` value, I'm treating that as a parameter.

This has the advantage of doing just one subquery.

Answer (score 4):

You're close! Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM STATUS
WHERE instituitionid IN (
        SELECT instituitionid
        FROM STATUS
        WHERE recid = recid
        )
    AND filename IN (
        SELECT filename
        FROM STATUS
        WHERE recid = recid
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Rocky. I expect  the inner select query to return a single instituitionid & filename. Would IN be required for that? Actually I was not sure my query was even right, and just wrote it as logical example for what I want.. Any way to simplify the code?! (Do I really need to write 2 inner selects which are basically just returning different columns of the same resultset?)

Comment: You could use "=" instead of "IN" since 1 row will be returned, but don't you need an @recid in there somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This would give you all of them including where b.recid = @recid

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM Status AS a
INNER JOIN Status AS b
ON a.instituitionid = b.instituitionid 
AND a.filename = b.filename
WHERE a.recid = @recid
```

Comment: Both your and @Ann L.'s answers work like a charm. Thanks a lot. Any idea on which would be better performance wise/lesser resource consuming?

Comment: I'm going to guess mine, or that they will be the same.  You can add these 3 lines and tell us:  declare @@starttime datetime;
set @@starttime = getdate(); --RUN SQL HERE; select datediff(MILLISECOND, @@starttime, getdate() )   (use single at sign, stackoverflow takes single as "at user"